# Can i colour part of the same 3D text which was converted from 2D text. ( Convert mesh to curve )

Tags: color, text-object

I really need to know how to color part of the same 3D text which i converted from 2D text. ( i added the text and converted it to curve and now it is one big object)
I want to change A's and D's emission color but keep rest of it blue

[image]

**2ND SS** https://gyazo.com/c0b664b12e43b4c160ecff892ec24509

Comment: hello, if you want to give it different colors you need to convert it to mesh or keep it a curve but use some procedural trick in the Node editor, but you should give some precision on what you want to do exactly

Comment: What kind of procedural tricks?

Comment: put a gradient so only some parts are colored with some color, but again please describe what you want exactly, also do you have a reason to keep it a curve (but it can be interesting to solve it as a curve)

Comment: oh ok you want A and D to have a different color  ;)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1vFSsCGBRy0JoxIpLCz6qug8RJF7CO1cY?usp=sharing 
Can you open it?

Comment: Also dunno why, when im converting it back to mesh and want to asign material to part of the mesh in edit mode ( by marking it and clicking asign)  it changes whole object ( i mean these 3 words)

Comment: about your deleted question: you must have switched from Cycles to Eevee, not sure Displacement works with Eevee

Comment: Thank you so much <3 it is solution to question why my neons dont work :D

Comment: oh ok, could you please tell a bit more, were you able to give it 2 colors?

Comment: Yes i was able and i get the result what i want, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a *Gradient* and a *ColorRamp* node to change the color along the curve. That said, I don't know how you can make the gradient follow the curve, someone may have an answer, here I kept the gradient horizontal.

[image]

And of course, you could convert your curve to mesh, in that case use a b&w mask as a factor in a *Mix* shader to go from a color to another one:

- Convert your mesh to curve, unwrap it with the *Smart UV Project* mode.
- Give it an *Image Texture* node. Paint it in black and white. It will be the mask that will separate your 2 colors.
- Now organize your nodes, plug the b&w picture in the factor of your Mix shader.

[image]

Another solution would be to parent a straight mesh pipe to bones (maybe with a *Spline IK* constraint) then twist the bones the way you want (or the curve in the case of a *Spline IK*), the texture will follow.

[image]